# xpath how to choose all elements matching

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Need to getText from all elements how on the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMXAA.png)

I don`t know why it takes text only from the first element

This is my Xpath:

```
//ul[@class='holders-list ng-scope']//li//article//div//div[@class='price-different clearfix']//ul//li//strong
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? you should also post your Java code and html.

Comment: How are we to know what distinguishes those HTML elements from all the others? Or where the text is relative to the distinguishable elements.

Comment: Please share your html so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following method may works,

use `driver.findElementsBy` method and store the values in a list , the list will contains all the xpaths

eg : 
store the web elements into a list and use a for each loop to iterate over it

```
List<WebElement> valueList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='holders-list ng-scope']//li//article//div//div[@class='price-different clearfix']//ul//li//strong"));

for(WebElement value:valueList){
    System.out.println(value.getText());
}
```